# Laravel - model self reference belongsToMany with other relation and query with multiple restrictions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model, relationship

I have 3 tables:

buildings:

```
+-----+-------------+-----------+--------------------------+------------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| id  | order_flag  |   type    |           key            | unit_cost  | unit_produce  |     created_at       |     updated_at      |
+-----+-------------+-----------+--------------------------+------------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|  1  |         10  | resource  | building1                |        10  |            0  | 2015-01-30 08:54:44  | 2015-01-30 08:54:44 |
|  2  |         20  | resource  | building2                |         5  |            0  | 2015-01-30 08:54:44  | 2015-01-30 08:54:44 |
|  3  |         30  | resource  | building3                |        10  |            0  | 2015-01-30 08:54:44  | 2015-01-30 08:54:44 |
|  4  |         10  | basic     | building4                |         0  |           25  | 2015-01-30 08:54:44  | 2015-01-30 08:54:44 |
+-----+-------------+-----------+--------------------------+------------+---------------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

building_user:

```
+-----+--------------+----------+--------+----------------------+---------------------+
| id  | building_id  | user_id  | level  |     created_at       |     updated_at      |
+-----+--------------+----------+--------+----------------------+---------------------+
|  1  |           2  |      12  |     3  | 2015-01-30 08:52:57  | 2015-01-30 08:55:37 |
|  2  |           4  |      12  |     1  | 2015-01-30 08:53:53  | 2015-01-30 08:53:53 |
|  3  |           1  |      12  |     2  | 2015-01-30 08:54:08  | 2015-01-30 08:55:10 |
+-----+--------------+----------+--------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

building_require:

```
+-----+--------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+---------------------+
| id  | building_id  | require_id  | level  |     created_at       |     updated_at      |
+-----+--------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+---------------------+
|  1  |           1  |          4  |     1  | 2015-01-30 08:54:44  | 2015-01-30 08:54:44 |
|  2  |           3  |          1  |     5  | 2015-01-30 08:54:44  | 2015-01-30 08:54:44 |
+-----+--------------+-------------+--------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

I write this relations in the building model:

```
    # Building Require another Building(s)
    public function requires() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Building', 'building_require', 'building_id', 'require_id')->withPivot(array(
            'level',
            'updated_at',
            'created_at'
        ));
    }

    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withPivot(array('level'));
    }
```

> Now I want select ALL the buildings from table buildings.. with
>   following restrictions:

1. If there is no entry from the building in the building_require table, this building can be in the result.
2. If this building has an entry in the building_require table, there must be a check if there is an entry in the building_user table, where the building_id is the same as the required_id in the building_required table.

(example building_id 1 needs building_id 4 and building_id 3 needs an entry for building_id 1.)

additional (and this is the difficult part) to this there must be a check if the entry in the building_user table has a level value >= as the level in the building_require table defined.

So summary:

> In
>   this case building_id 1 needs an entry in building_user where building_id is 4
>   and the level is at least 1. building_id 3 needs an entry in
>   building_user where building_id is 1 and the level is at least 5.  So - building_id 1 and 3 has a required building. building with
>   id 2 and 4 are in the result without restrictions.
>   **In this case the only the building_id 3 is not allowed.** because the level of building_id 1 in the building_user table is only 2 and not at least 5.

for me it is very difficult, and I think this is not the best solution, and this is sadly without the check for the level value:

```
# all buildings there has a required building:
$allRequiredBuildingIds = DB::table('building_require')->lists('building_id');

# if user has buildings, this buildings must remove from $allRequiredBuildingIds
if(Sentry::getUser()->buildings()->count() > 0) {
    # list all building_id 's of the user_building table
    $userBuildingIds = Sentry::getUser()->buildings()->lists('building_id');
    # list all building_id's of the buildings there are required and already stored in the building_user table
    $userBuildingRequiredIds = DB::table('building_require')->whereIn('require_id', $userBuildingIds)->lists('building_id');
    # there are all the building_id's which are not allowed to display
    $allRequiredBuildingIds = array_values(array_diff($allRequiredBuildingIds,$userBuildingRequiredIds));
}

# if there are buildings there are not allowed to display?
if(count($allRequiredBuildingIds) > 0) {
    $buildings = Building::whereType($type)->whereNotIn('id', $allRequiredBuildingIds)->paginate(10);
}else{
    $buildings = Building::whereType($type)->paginate(10);
}
```

Can somebody help me, to optimize it, and integrate the level check?
My head is pounding.

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory that this may work, but I've yet to test it. I think the key is only using the Join inside of there whereHas closure, thus allowing the Eloquent builder to remain active.

```
Building::doesntHave('requires')
    ->orWhereHas('users', function($q) {
        $q->join('building_require', 'building_user.building_id', '=', 'building_require.required_id')
          ->where('building_user.level', '>=', 'building_require.level');
    })->get();
```

It will generate a query like this:

```
select * from `buildings` where (
  select count(*) from `building_require` as `x` where `x`.`building_id` = `buildings`.`id`
) < 1 or (
  select count(*) from `users` 
  inner join `building_user` on `users`.`id` = `building_user`.`user_id` 
  inner join `building_require` on `building_user`.`building_id` = `building_require`.`required_id` 
  where `building_user`.`building_id` = `buildings`.`id` 
  and `building_user`.`level` >= building_require.level
) >= 1
```

---

Unfortunately, this won't do the trick. It'll return the building_require.required_id buildings instead of the building_require.building_id ones. I managed to figure out the right query in raw SQL, but I'm not sure how to fix it in Eloquent:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6837bf/19/0)

```
select * from `buildings` where (
  select count(*) from `building_require` as `x` where `x`.`building_id` = `buildings`.`id`
) < 1 or (
  select count(*) from `users` 
  inner join `building_user` on `users`.`id` = `building_user`.`user_id` 
  inner join `building_require` on `building_user`.`building_id` = `building_require`.`required_id` 
  where building_require.building_id = buildings.id
  and `building_user`.`level` >= building_require.level
) >= 1;
```

Comment: thanks for answer. 
But I got an error If I use your code:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 (SQL: select * from `buildings` where (select count(*) from `building_require` as `self_8ebed67ebfeab2e90676c66005049e5a` where `self_8ebed67ebfeab2e90676c66005049e5a`.`building_id` = `buildings`.`id`) < 1 or (select count(*) from `users` inner join `building_user` on `users`.`id` = `building_user`.`user_id` inner join `building_require` on `building_user`.`building_id` = ``.`require_id` and `building_user`.`level` >= ? where `building_user`.`building_id` = `buildings`.`id`) >= 1)

Comment: @goldlife I think I fixed it, can you try again?

Comment: no sry... also not work. I updated your query also with a syntax error after your where statement :  ->where('building_user.level', '>=', 'building_require.level');
      }); - you miss a ")" . and it is required_id not require_id. but nothing works. It gives me the mysql general error. but thanks for your answer... ;)

Comment: no luck. I can fix your code to a working query: 
`$buildings = Building::doesntHave('requires')
            ->orWhereHas('users', function($q) {
                $q->join('building_require', 'building_user.building_id', '=', 'building_require.require_id')
                  ->where('building_user.level', '>=', 'building_require.level');
            })->get();` But - I got all the buildings back. There is also no check for the user_id in building_user. If I add the user_id check in the where of the join, I get all times only ONE building back, whatever a level is in building_user table present.

Comment: @goldlife hm...I think i figured out a working SQL statement for it by making a tiny change to the one generated by laravel (the "where" statement). Unfortunately, not sure howto get Laravel to generate that part of the statement correctly. I've appended it to the answer. If I figure out the proper way of doing this, I'll make a new answer for it.